# Update template var in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

New to Angular2.  My template shows `connected` as `false` when I startup my app.  Then the console logs `connected to socket.io` but `connected` still reads false in my template.  How can I set things up so that when the connection status changes `connected` will read correctly in my template?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

let io = require('socket.io-client');
let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4300');


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: require('./app.component.pug'),

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    connected = false;

    ngOnInit(){
        socket.on('connect', ()=> {
            this.connected = true;
            console.log('connected to socket.io');
        })
    }

    getSocketStatus(){
       console.log(this.connected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the variable out of the update-cycle of Angular. So you need to tell it manually, that something has changed. See this for a detailed explanation of the Angular Change Detection http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

This should do the trick (untested)

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

let io = require('socket.io-client');
let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4300');


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: require('./app.component.pug'),

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    connected = false;

    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {};

    ngOnInit(){
        socket.on('connect', ()=> {
            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.connected = true;
            });

            console.log('connected to socket.io');
        })
    }

    getSocketStatus(){
       console.log(this.connected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {};   

ngOnInit(){
        socket.on('connect', ()=> {

            this.connected = true;
            this._cd.detectChanges() // detect the changes
            console.log('connected to socket.io');
        })
    }
```

Or , to fix @Volker's answer , you can run the whole socket.io's functions in zone  :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.zone.run(() => {
       socket.on('connect', ()=> {
            this.connected = true;
            console.log('connected to socket.io');
          })
     });
}
```